# How to extract text with Jsoup from table

Tags: java, html, web, web-crawler, jsoup

Maybe someone could help me with exracting information from html using jsoup?

Information needed is 23.90

```
<tr>
  <td class="leftcell" valign="top">
  <div onclick=
  "ShowHideTravelDetails('bookingPrice_TaxesToggleBox', 
'bookingPrice_TaxesToggleIcon', '/Images');" class="productheader">...</div>
</td>
<td class="rightcell emphasize" align="right" 
valign="bottom">$23.90</td></tr>
```

I can see it in few places in the html doc.
I've tried using

```
Elements taxes = doc.select("td.rightcell.emphasize");
```

but it is not working.

Also tried extracting info as from table:

```
   Elements table = doc.select("table[class=selectiontable]");
        Elements rows = table.get(0).select("td[class^=rightcell emphasize]");
        for (Element row : rows) {


            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            System.out.println(tds.get(13));
```

Comment: please add a code not screen shot

Comment: The first code snippet looks good to me. In the second one you're retrieving `td`s and calling them `rows` then trying to retrieve a child `td` ; I guess you wanted to retrieve `tr`s instead (but then the class selector doesn't make sense anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this 
I assume that you have a code like this . You need to do nested level iteration to get the result .

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html ="<table class=\"selectiontable\">\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "  <td class=\"leftcell\" valign=\"top\">\n" +
                "  <div onclick=\n" +
                "  \"ShowHideTravelDetails('bookingPrice_TaxesToggleBox', \n" +
                "'bookingPrice_TaxesToggleIcon', '/Images');\" class=\"productheader\">...</div>\n" +
                "</td>\n" +
                "<td class=\"rightcell emphasize\" align=\"right\" \n" +
                "valign=\"bottom\">$23.90</td></tr>\n" +
                "</table>";


        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements elements = document.select(".selectiontable");
         for (Element element :elements){
             for (Element row : element.select("tr")) {
                 Elements tds = row.select("td");
                 if (tds.size() > 1) {
                     System.out.println(tds.get(1).text());
                 }
             }
         }
    }


}
```

**output:**

```
$23.90
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I have the problem that I am trying to parse whole html doc by Document document = Jsoup.parse(doc.toString()); and it is not founding anything. i.e. no output of 23.90. May it be due to the fact that this number appears in few places in html file?

Comment: @brigitte without full html i can't fix your issue . Just share full html or at least from the `table` tags .I will sorted out .

Comment: ok lets take i click `98.80` what you wanted to get the result?

Comment: Taxes - there is a box that appears on the right side after selecting one of the Fares. And for 98.80 it is 23.90